# CSS negative margin difference when loading elements dynamically and straight through the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The position of the element differs when loading straight from server and dynamically through CSS.

I am using the same CSS class on both occasions but different results.

The `margin-bottom` is set to `-40px`, the location of the element is different when I am loading the element through PHP and dynamically through jQuery.

The CSS class:

```
.iconView .adLocation {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  color: #FFF;
  height: 18px;
  font-size: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -40px;
  width: 188px;
}
```

I inspected the CSS of the element via chrome dev tools & `margin-top` is set properly to `40px`. I can't post a preview not enough reputation. sry.

Comment: Please add in the code for reference.

Comment: Please edit the question and add your code, don't post it in a comment.

Comment: So you "load" the element from PHP, then from CSS, then from jQuery? I don't get it.

Comment: I have multiple pages. When the user initially visit the page the data is loaded straight from the server. But once the user clicks next or previous the data is loaded via ajax & for this the response is in json format. So I prepare the elements dynamically through jQuery and then appends it to the parent element.

Comment: still no luck. If it was overridden the dev tools shows a strike through the margin rule & it doesn't appear to be overridden. Anyway I tried your answer & it did't workout.

Comment: I tried it, still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have defined your element position absolute, so you can use `top: -40px;` instead of using `margin-top: -40px;`

Comment: Thank you. Using just top instead of margin-top worked...! :)